# Does "Deployment Target" do more than control compiler warnings?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I recently submitted an update for an application using a deployment target of 3.2 (it was 3.0 in my debug settings, but I must have overlooked the distribution settings). But on the application setup in iTunes Connect, I indicated the minimum supported OS version to be 3.0.  Now I'm getting reports from users on OS 3.1 that the app won't run.

I've built new binaries with the fixed deployment target, but I have no way to test it.  I don't have any devices running OS < 3.2, and the simulator won't go below 3.2 either (why not?!).  I'd hate to submit this as a fix, only to have it still not work...

So does the deployment target setting do more than just control the compiler warnings (e.g. if I used an API only available in a newer SDK)?  As far as I know, I don't use any APIs that were not available in OS 3.0 (there are no warnings, either).

Comment: How did you go about setting the minimum supported OS version in iTunes Connect?  That should be pulled automatically from the Info.plist in your submitted binary and shouldn't be something you can set.

Comment: @Brad, hmm, I was sure I had specified that when configuring the update in iTunes Connect, but now I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone's iOS is of an earlier version than the deployment target, the app will refuse to start.

I once had an app whose deployment target was 3.1.  In an update, I accidentally set the deployment target to 4.0.  My iOS 3.1 customers were then unable to run the app.  I submitted another update whose only change was putting the deployment target back to 3.1.  It worked for them again.

The testing situation is unfortunate, yes.  If anybody knows of a way to test earlier versions without having an extra device dedicated to that task, I hope they chime in.

[This article](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: To build on this slightly; your deployment target is recorded in your Info.plist, and subsequently used by both the iTunes Store for information display and by the device to determine whether it can run the thing. It's actually quite important to test on a device if you can, since if you attempt to use APIs that don't exist on the earlier OS then your app will fail to launch, appearing the same as if it had crashed.

Comment: I wasn't sure if setting the deployment target back would do it, but it sounds like it will.  Thanks

Comment: Turns out if you do `[UIPopoverController alloc]` anywhere (even if it's not actually executed) the app will crash as soon as it starts.  Using `[NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController") alloc]` works around this. I actually was aware of this when the SDK still supported running on iOS 3.1.3, but when they dropped that option, it dropped out of my mind as well.